# How can I get the original dimensions of a raster image in SVG?

Tags: javascript, image, svg

In HTML, it is possible to know the original dimensions of an image by using `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` properties. For example:

```
<img
    src="img.png"
    onload="console.log({width:this.naturalWidth, height:this.naturalHeight});"
/>
```

But the `image` element in SVG doesn’t have these properties. For example the following code returns `undefined` for both properties:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <image
        xlink:href="img.png"
        onload="console.log({width:this.naturalWidth, height:this.naturalHeight});"
    />
</svg>
```

For now I solved this by using a function that loads the image in a `img` HTML element by using the `Image()` constructor:

```
getRasterSize("img.png", function(size) {
    console.log(size);
});

function getRasterSize(rasterURL, callback) {
    var newImg = new Image();
    newImg.src = rasterURL;
    newImg.onload = function() {
        var rasterSize = {
            width: newImg.naturalWidth,
            height: newImg.naturalHeight
        };
        if (typeof callback !== "undefined") callback(rasterSize);
    };
}
```

But I would like to know if it is possible to get the original dimensions of the image directly from the SVG `image` element without loading the image in a `img` HTML element first.

Comment: If you draw an image without `width` and `height` attributes the image will take the natural size. Then in JS you can call `theImage.getBBox()`. This will return an object with `x`, `y` `width` and `height`. I hope it helps.

Comment: @exaneta only in Chrome I believe. Elsewhere you'll get nothing.